# Problem with escaping HTML characters in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, escaping, helpermethods

I use `foo` helper function in my view:

```
 <%= foo ["hello", "stack", "overflow"] %>
```

When `foo` is defined like this:

```
def foo(arr)
  result = ''
  arr.each do |a|
    result += content_tag(:div, a)
  end
  result
end
```

The page renders:

```
<div>hello</div><div>stack</div><div>overflow</div>
```

But, if change `foo`'s definition to be:

```
def foo(arr)
  content_tag(:div, arr[0]) + content_tag(:div, arr[1]) + content_tag(:div, arr[2])
end
```

I get the expected result:

```
hello
stack
overflow
```

How would you fix `foo`'s definition above to get the expected result ? (i.e. I don't want the characters to be escaped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def foo(arr)
  result = ''
  arr.each do |a|
    result += content_tag(:div, a)
  end
  raw result
end
```

Edit.

To be clearer, you're creating a string and Rails doesn't know whether or not it's safe to display.
To be even more precise, Rails has no doubt concerning the content_tags it creates.

So you could solve your problem telling rails your initializer string is safe:

```
def foo(arr)
  result = ''.html_safe
  arr.each do |a|
    result += content_tag(:div, a)
  end
  result
end
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved the problem. However, I still wonder why `raw` is needed. Could you elaborate on that please ?